# editform jquery value returns undefined

Tags: jquery, cewp

I've added the following code into a CEWP part at the top of the Editform.aspx page (using SharePoint 2013)

```
<html>
<script src="https://oursites/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var s1 = $("select[title = 'Request ID']");
        alert(s1);
        var s2 = s1.val();
        alert(s2);
        var s3 = $("select[title = 'Request ID']").val();
        alert(s3);
        var s4 = $("select[title = 'Request ID']").text();
        alert(s4);
        var text = $("select[title$='Request ID'] :selected").text();
        alert(text);

    });

</script>
</html>
```

However, I am unable to retrieve the field value.

The results of the alerts are:

S1 [object Object]
S2 undefined
S3 undefined
S4 -empty alert window- 
 
text -empty alert window-

My aim is to use values from the form to hide columns. The hide function works fine, but I just can't access the form values. What have I done wrong? Thanks!

**SOLVED:**

The code had to be

```
var s3 = $("input[title='Request ID']").val();
```

If any newbies (like me) see this post, check out this website

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/07/28/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-started.aspx

Comment: Please remember to post your solution as an actual answer as soon as you are able to do that

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

The code had to be

```
var s3 = $("input[title='Request ID']").val();
```

If any newbies (like me) see this post, check out this website

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/07/28/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-started.aspx